# NServiceBus.Host.exe is missing while installing NServiceBus.Host on aspnetcore 2 in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio-2017, nservicebus, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to run NServiceBus with AspNetCore2 on visual studio 2017. While I install NServiceBus(Version 7.0.0-beta0001) and NServiceBus.Host(Version 8.0.0-beta0001) through nuget, it says package installed successfully.

However, when i try to check installed dll's and exe files of NServiceBus within bin/debug folder, it's not there.

Quick observations i made are, NServiceBus (version 7.0...) is installed correctly whereas NServiceBus.Host (version 8.0....) is showing a warning message under nuget folder in visual studio:

```
Package 'NServiceBus.Host 8.0.0-beta0001' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1' instead of the project target framework '.NETCoreApp,Version=v2.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.
```

Please help me to resolve this issue or point me to correct question if it's already been answered (which i could not find in SO)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NServiceBus.Host is being phased out for the reasons specified [here](https://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/upgrades/host-7to8). Long story short, in .NET Core it does not add much of a value and has more cons.

You can however, still run the NServiceBus process in a console app. Have a look at the self-hosting sample [here](https://docs.particular.net/samples/hosting/self-hosting/).

Comment: thanks @Hadi, that's what i get after reviewing official example code of NServiceBus and aspnet core 2 [here](https://docs.particular.net/samples/web/send-from-aspnetcore-webapi/)